# The Phrase "You're brazen"

Tags: idioms

Is the phrase "**you're brazen**"  used frequently in American English? If so, could I respond to someone who isults me with it?

Comment: We're [much more likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Don%27t+be+brazen%2CDon%27t+be+presumptuous%2CYou+are+brazen%2CYou+are+presumptuous&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=30) to accuse someone of being ***presumptuous*** than ***brazen***. How you respond is up to you - there is no "set response".

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/brazen) reckons brazen is used "occasionally", in top 30000 words. I imagine you could go many months without hearing "you're brazen" specifically. Of course you can respond to it; why would you not be able to respond? Please clarify and expand, or this question will be closed.

Comment: (I don't think *brazen* and *presumptuous* mean exactly the same thing - brazen is stronger, with more of a sense of shamelessness and total disregard for conventions. Presumptuousness can be a lot milder, e.g. taking a cookie without being offered. But certainly that supports the argument that brazen is less common.)